# Method not found: 'System.Object Sitecore.Caching.Cache.GetValue(System.Object)'

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.2

Recently after upgrading to 8.2 when i try to login iam getting this error

Method not found: 'System.Object Sitecore.Caching.Cache.GetValue(System.Object)'.

https://www.screencast.com/t/AH2YgjcPE

Comment: Can you verify that all files (especially in the bin, config and sitecore folders) match the ones from a clean Sitecore instance? Most of the time issues like this are solved with a file compare..

Comment: Check this https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/10/t/3875